# How to write out a spreadsheet opened with readonly in openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

for performance reasons I have loaded in a spreadsheet as readonly in python
`self.data = load_workbook(filename,read_only=True, data_only=True)`.  I want to be able to now write it out.  Is there anyway to copy or dump out a read_only workbook so that it can be written out as an XLSX?  Before anyone comments, yes I do understand the concept and definition of "read_only", but I also know there are clever people out there that can figure out ways around things.

Comment: So you want to take your read_only workbook and and save it as a new workbook?

Comment: You can combine read-only and write-only modes but you will have to do this row by row, cell by cell.

Comment: @jezza_99 Yes, I want to use read_only to open, but write it out later to an XLSX.  During the processing of the XLSX, the code has the opportunity to update/augment the data and I need that new version saved off.  Loading the spreadsheet for read_write takes a long time (like 10 minutes on a MB Pro with 32GB ram and an I9)

Comment: Then do as @Charlie recommended; load the workbook in in read-only, create a new workbook in write-only and copy across row by row, cell by cell, altering/updating the data as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with.  Problem is, it costs about the same amount of time as doing a read without the read_only set.

```py
    def cloneReadOnlyWorksheet(self):
        destWB = Workbook()
        for sheet in orgWorkbook:
            cloneSheet(destWB,sheet)

    def cloneSheet(self, wb, ws1):
        ws2 = wb.create_sheet(ws1.title)
        mr = ws1.max_row
        mc = ws1.max_column
        for row in range (1, mr + 1):
            for column in range (1, mc + 1):
                cell = ws1.cell(row,column)
                if cell.value != None:
                    new_cell = ws2.cell(row, column, value=cell.value)
                    if cell.has_style:
                        new_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
                        new_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
                        new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)
                        new_cell.number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
                        new_cell.protection = copy(cell.protection)
                        new_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
```